# Displaying only single most recent line of a command's output

Tags: bash, terminal, output

How can I print a command output like one from `rm -rv *` in a single line ? I think it would need `\r` but I can't figure out how.

I would need to have something like this :

From:

```
removed /path/file1
removed /path/file2
removed /path/file3
```

To : `Line 1 : removed /path/file1`

Then : `Line 1 : removed /path/file2`

Then : `Line 1 : removed /path/file3`

**EDIT** : I may have been misunderstood, I want to have the whole process beeing printing in a single same line, changing as the command outputs an another line (like `removed /path/file123`)

**EDIT2** : The output is sometimes too long to be display in on line (very long path). I would need something that considers that problem too :
`/very/very/very/long/path/to/a/very/very/very/far/file/with-a-very-very-very-long-name1`
`/very/very/very/long/path/to/a/very/very/very/far/file/with-a-very-very-very-long-name2`
`/very/very/very/long/path/to/a/very/very/very/far/file/with-a-very-very-very-long-name3`

Comment: Can you give a sample input and an output needed.

Comment: You want each file name to erase the previous one, all shown on the same line as the command runs. Is that right?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yep !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a helper function:

```
shopt -s checkwinsize # ensure that COLUMNS is available w/ window size

oneline() {
  local ws
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if (( ${#line} >= COLUMNS )); then
      # Moving cursor back to the front of the line so user input doesn't force wrapping
      printf '\r%s\r' "${line:0:$COLUMNS}"
    else
      ws=$(( COLUMNS - ${#line} ))
      # by writing each line twice, we move the cursor back to position
      # thus: LF, content, whitespace, LF, content
      printf '\r%s%*s\r%s' "$line" "$ws" " " "$line"
    fi
  done
  echo
}
```

Used as follows:

```
rm -rv -- * 2>&1 | oneline
```

---

To test this a bit more safely, one might use:

```
for f in 'first line' 'second line' '3rd line'; do echo "$f"; sleep 1; done | oneline
```

...you'll see that that test displays `first line` for a second, then `second line` for a second, then `3rd line` for a second.

Comment: What is the `2>&1` part for ?

Comment: @Blaxou, to ensure that we're correctly handling content written to stderr.

Comment: The fact that I'm showing an example demonstrator that doesn't use `cp` / `rm` / etc. but instead uses `echo` to generate test data should answer that question implicitly.

Comment: I tried, your example and i't working but in my case, it doesn't seem to work...
Here is my code :
`rm -rv ~/Desktop/BACKUPS/'USB 8GB GS'/ 2>&1 | oneline`
`cp -Rv /Volumes/'USB 8GB GS'/ ~/Desktop/BACKUPS/'USB 8GB GS'/ 2>&1 | oneline`

Comment: Worked for me . I skipped function like this:  `touch ff1 ff2 ff3;rm -fv ff1 ff2 ff3 |while read -r line;do ws=$(( COLUMNS - ${#line} ));printf '\r%s%*s\r%s' "$line" "$ws" " " "$line";sleep 2;done;echo`

Comment: @Blaxou, could you provide a description of the behavior you're seeing more precise than "doesn't work"?

Comment: Ok so both Charles's and @GeorgeVasilou 's examples work. But when I use them (The function or George's) in my script it prints every line as if the function wasn't there.
EDIT : It alignes output in a strange way, with end of lines beeing cut
EDIT2 : I think it's due to the fact that some line are too long to be displayed in one line and make the function misscalculate

Comment: I tried with a very little terminal font and it seems to work as expected surely because all output lines could be displayed in one line... So I'll need to find a workaround in order to display the whole process in two single lines

Comment: See amended version, which fixes the case by printing only the first COLUMNS characters of output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "status line" result that is showing the last line output by the program where the line gets over-written by the next line when it comes out you can send the output for the command through a short shell while loop like this:

```
  YourCommand | while read line ; do echo -n "$line"$'  ...[lots of spaces]... \r' ; done
```

The [Lots of spaces] is needed in case a shorter line comes after a longer line.  The short line needs to overwrite the text from the longer line or you will see residual characters from the long line.

The echo -n $' ... \r' sends a literal carriage return without a line-feed to the screen which moves the position back to the front of the line but doesn't move down a line.

If you want the text from your command to just be output in 1 long line, then
pipe the output of any command through this sed command and it should replace the carriage returns with spaces.  This will put the output all on one line.  You could change the space to another delimiter if desired.

```
 your command  | sed ':rep; {N;}; s/\n/ /; {t rep};'
```

:rep; is a non-command that marks where to go to in the {t rep} command.

{N;} will join the current line to the next line.
It doesn't remove the carriage return but just puts the 2 lines in the buffer to be used for following commands.

s/\n/ /;   Says to replace the carriage return character with a space character. They space is between the second and third/ characters.
You may need to replace \r\n depending on if the file has line feeds. UNIX files don't unless they came from a pc and haven't been converted.

{t rep}; says that if the match was found in the s/// command then go to the :rep; marker.

This will keep joining lines, removing the \n, then jumping to :rep; until there are no more likes to join.

Comment: Where is the space exactly ? Between `:rep;` and `{N;};` ?

Comment: @Blaxou:  the space is in the s/\n/[space]/; command it says replace the \n (carriage return) character with a literal space character.  The space is between the second / and the third / in the s/x/y/; command.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... I tried to replace `sed ':rep; {N;}; s/\n/ /; {t rep};'` with `sed ':rep; {N;}; s/\r/ /; {t rep};'` and it just displays the output each line

Comment: It is possible that the output contains both \r and \n so you may need to have s/\r\n/ /;  to get the carriage return and line feeds to get replaced.  To see what bytes are coming out of the previous command run the output through a command like  "| od -c -t x1"  This will print the output as characters and bytes.  look for bytes like  10 == \r and 13 == \n and see which ones are there in the output.

Comment: It only contains `\n` bytes, no `\r`

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk -- could you explain how this achieves the OP's stated goal? As Blaxou says, I don't see any `\r`s here, so how are we going back to the beginning of the line to update/rewrite it when an additional line comes in?

Comment: ...so that's just forming all your lines of input into one really long line of output, and letting it wrap onto multiple lines on the terminal. That doesn't accomplish the stated goal -- having one line of console output with its contents removed and replaced as new contents come in. While the question was a bit ambiguous as initially written, see the comment by John Kugelman asking the OP to clarify -- posted prior to your answer -- and the OP's response affirming the proposed interpretation.

Comment: @Charles Duffy:  Thanks, you are right, My answer was doing something different than was requested after looking at the comments.  I added a new solution to my answer that will do what was requested.

Comment: You might test in cases where the incoming lines are longer than terminal length. (This is a place where the OP pointed out flaws in my first attempt, and it looks to me like there are similar issues remaining here).